# Google API returns a response 200 empty JSON

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

I'm trying to make an HTTP GET request to the [Google Street View Publish API](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/), inside a Google Apps Script script, to fetch the photos list and save metadata about them to a Google spreadsheet.

The code I'm using on the script to contact the API:

```
var url = 'https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos?fields=nextPageToken%2Cphotos&key=' + API_KEY;

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {
        //the accessToken is borrowed from the Apps Script Infrastructure `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`
        //source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aP6pxK3jexc
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
});
console.log('API response:\n' + response);
```

And including the Street View Auth at the script's manifest `oauthscopes.json` file:

```
...
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/streetviewpublish", 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
]
...
```

Been using a time-based trigger to run the script every 15 min, **and it has been working just fine for couple of hours** and returning a JSON object with the photos on the account, until the API stopped to return a response, and it's now just returning an empty JSON object `{}`.

I don't think I consumed the quote for the API usage, my numbers from the GCP dashboard as follows:

[image: Quote Numbers 1]

[image: Quote Numbers 2]

Tried to create another `API KEY` and use it at the script, but still no luck.

Also, when tried to test the API from the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_GB#search/maps/streetviewpublish/v1/streetviewpublish.photos.list?fields=photos&_h=3&), authorize and execute, it gives me the response code `200` with an empty JSON object as well.
This has been working before, but, now it doesn't!

**What might be the problem here?**

---

## Edit:

As suggested at the comments, I tried to:

- Call the API endpoint with or without the API key and the other parameters, as follows:

`https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos?fields=nextPageToken%2Cphotos&key=' + API_KEY`

`https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos?key=' + API_KEY`

`https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos`

- Also, tried to revoke the access for both the Google APIs Explorer and the script on Google Apps Script, from the [account security checkup](https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup/). Which because of it when tried to run it again, it opened a popup window to ask for the authorization/permission again, which I granted as well.
- Tried to log out of the Google account & clearing the browser's cache.

Yet, still, the same empty JSON object response!

---

## Edit 2:

- Also stopped the script's time-based triggers 2 days ago, still no luck!

Comment: have you uploaded photos via this API already?  if not, an empty JSON with 200 response would be normal.

Comment: @Erich, I'm not trying to upload photo, I'm using the API endpoint `GET https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos?fields=nextPageToken%2Cphotos&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` to get the list of the photos I uploaded before. At the APIs explorer it's `streetviewpublish.photos.list`. And yes, I have photos on the account now already.

Comment: Your code? Per user quota is 60. Haven't you used it up?

Comment: what happens when you remove `nextPageToken%2C` from the request?

Comment: @TheMaster I updated the question to include the code I use at the script to contact the API, please note I was running a time-based trigger every 15 minutes.

Comment: @Erich  When I remove the parameters from the request at the Google APIs Explorer now I get response code `200` with empty JSON object.

Comment: It look like there is no photos Id parameters. Based on documentation it must be photoIds=<id1>&photoIds=<id2> in the url

Comment: @St3ph This is the documentation for the method I'm trying to use `photos.list`:  https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photos/list , I think the parameter you refer to is `filter`, and I understand it's an optional parameter, I don't see anything saying it's a **requirement** or a **must** be included parameter.

Comment: @TheMaster  the 60 quote is PER MINUTE! I don't think I used it up! I just run the the script once every 15 minutes.

Comment: Do you have a next page token? Could you try 1.`var url = 'https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos?key=' + API_KEY;` and 2. without a api key: `var url = 'https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos'`

Comment: This endpoint is for photos you published. Are you using an account that publish photos? Just to be sure.

Comment: @TheMaster I tried both suggestions you suggested, but, unfortunately, still the same response!

Comment: @St3ph  Yes, the account has 360 photos at it, and the API was responding with JSON object before with the photo urls, view counts and everything!

Comment: `and it has been working just fine for couple of hours` If you can't access the photos even with api explorer, you might want to contact Google support or open a new issue at bugtracker

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I've just started using this API and I'm running into the same problem. I'm trying to get the list of photos from a user that I know has published photos, yet all I'm getting is a 200 response and an empty JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says that `pageSize` defaults to 100. This is not the case. If you specify the `pageSize` parameter, it returns a response with photos.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Setting `pageSize` to `100` manually, works like a charm.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, thank you!